# Bash Kill Java process using JPS

Tags: bash

I am trying to create a simple bash script that will kill a specific java process. JPS seems to be the most suitable candidate so I quickly wrote this:

```
jps | grep my_process_name | awk '{print $1}'
```

In the terminal this works great and I get back the `PID` of the java process `my_process_name`. However when I put that into a quick script like this:

```
stop_app() {
    echo 'Stopping running service...'
    PID=jps | grep halo | awk '{print $1}'
    kill -9 ${PID}
}
```

My `PID` seems to be empty! Any ideas?

Comment: Use command substitution to store the output of a command to a variable: `PID=$(jps | grep halo | awk '{print $1}')`

Comment: Note this suffices: `PID=$(jps | awk '/halo/{print $1}')`. No need to use `grep` in between.

Answer (score 1):

`PID="$(jps | grep halo | awk '{print $1}')"` ?